# Hardcopy all values with Macro although a filter is used

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
               A               B               
    1         Sales Price      Sales Price
    2         50
    3         20
    4         30
    5         40
    6         80
    7         50
    8         40
    9         20
    10        50
```

Now I want to use the following macro to hardcopy the values from Column A to Column B:

```
Sub Hardcopy()
Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A2:A10").Copy
Sheets(Sheet1).Range("B2:B10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
End Sub
```

This macro works perfectly. However, when I now set a filter ino column A so it looks for example like the following:

```
               A               B               
    1         Sales Price      Sales Price
    2         50
    7         50
    10        50
```

and i run the above macro again it will only hardcopy the filtered values.

I want that the macro does hardcopy all values no matter what kind of filter is set up.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: what kind of filter you have ? the code of it ? you can remove all filters, copy Column A to Column B, and then filter it back.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no 'smart' way to do this without looping through the source range and setting the values on the target range, for example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    CopyAllRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), 1, 2
End Sub

Sub CopyAllRows(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal lngSourceColumn As Long, ByVal lngTargetColumn As Long)

    Dim rngFilter As Range
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range

    'quit if no filter
    If ws.AutoFilterMode = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'get source range
    Set rngFilter = ws.AutoFilter.Range
    Set rngSource = rngFilter.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngFilter.Rows.Count - 1, lngSourceColumn)

    'assign values to target column (no clipboard)
    For Each rngCell In rngSource
        rngCell.Offset(0, lngTargetColumn - lngSourceColumn).Value = rngCell.Value
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```